# Получение значения предыдущего поля в AJAX

Tags: ajax, javascript

Уважаемые разработчики, мне нужна небольшая помощь по AJAX. Проблема в получении значения предыдущего поля. Код примерно такой

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" id="<?php echo $itemsrow['id']?>" onClick="ChangeCount(this.id)">
</form>
```

AJAX

```
var Request = null;
var Request = getXmlHttpRequest();
function ChangeCount (id)
{
    var value = 1;
    Request.open("get","items.php?id="+escape(id)+"&value="+escape(value),true);
    Request.send(null);
}
```

PHP писать не буду: слишком большой код, в общем этот PHP обрабатывает запрос и прибавляет к количеству плюс один. Возвращает обновленный результат. Проблема в том, что если поменять `value` на `id.previousSibling.value`, не проходит, а как подставить значение текстового поля, не знаю. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Код выделите как положено, невозможно прочитать

Comment: это HTML
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="button" id="<?php echo $itemsrow['id']?>" onClick="ChangeCount(this.id)">
    </form>
конец HTML---
это AJAX 
var Request = null;
var Request = getXmlHttpRequest();
function ChangeCount (id)
{
    var value = 1;
    Request.open("get","items.php?id="+escape(id)+"&value="+escape(value),true);
    Request.send(null);
}
это функция AJAX там в переменную value нужно подставить значение вводимое пользователем в текстовое поле формы

Comment: @Mixail, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: `id.parentNode.children[0].value`  как-то лучше смотрится, чем sibling.

Answer (score 1):

1. id - это id, строка. Неправильно обращаться к id.previousSibling, нужно вызывать document.getElementById(id).previousSibling;
2. `document.getElementById(id).previousSibling` - это text. между первым и вторым imput'ом идет пробел, который является текстовым элементом в dom. `document.getElementById(id).previousSibling.previousSibling` - будет первый input.

Правильным подходом будет обращение не к previousSibling, а поиск элемента по id или по имени. Например, так:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" />
    <input type="button" id="<?php echo $itemsrow['id']?>" onClick="ChangeCount(this.id)" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
var Request = null;
var Request = getXmlHttpRequest();
function ChangeCount (id)
{
    var value = document.getElementById('txt').value || "";
    // или var value = document.getElementsByName('txt')[0].value || ""; 
    Request.open("get","items.php?id="+escape(id)+"&value="+escape(value),true);
    Request.send(null);
}
```

Comment: не так. ``document.getElementsByName('txt')`` возращает коллекцию элементов. надо ``document.getElementsByName('txt')[0]``.
или ``document.getElementById('txt')`` в данном случае вернется сам элемент.

Comment: поставьте firebug и отлаживайте скрипты в нем (вариант DragonFly для оперы, F12 для IE).

Comment: я поставил document.getElementsByName('txt')[0] функция не отрабатывает

Comment: СПАСИБО ВСЕМ!!!правильно работает если поставить два previousSibling Огромное Спасибо Юре Иванову !!!

Comment: А здесь name и id задали?
``<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" />``

Answer (score 0):

Не с компьютера сейчас, поэтому без кода. Потом поправлю.
Вы передаете this.id в функцию, а нужно либо this передать, либо `document.getElementById(id).previousSibling.value`.
У String нет previousSibling.

Comment: я передаю this.id имено из за того что хочу достучаться до this.previousSibling а id у кнопок разные (это id номера записей из бд где нужно менять количество) я попробовал document.getElementsByClassName(class).previousSibling.value не работает наверно из за того что все выводится в цикле

Comment: Сделайте так и передайте в функцию this, а не this.id

   function ChangeCount (button){
        var value = 1;
        Request.open("get","items.php?id="+escape(button.id)+"&value="+escape(button.previousSibling.value),true);
         Request.send(null);
    }

Comment: ну сделал в принципе сначала было именно this а не this.id а как получить значение в текстовом инпуте?

Comment: `button.parentNode.children[0].value` как-то так

Comment: я прописал как в вашем коде но что то в нем не так то есть функция выполняется но значения не доходят